# DDD : create repository for an entity and its status

Tags: c#, tdd, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have an entity in my domain which I need to track its status. And I have a handler for this need. This status is like `InProgress`, `Completed` or `Deleted`. And I use CosmosDb, SQL API for storing that data.

Inside CosmosDb, I have created a container for those created entities and another container for its status. Therefore, inside the code, I have two repositories for those two containers.

```
internal interface EntityRepository
{
   Task AddAsync(Entity entity);
}

internal interface EntityStatusRepository
{
   Task AddAsync(EntityStatus entityStatus);
}
```

And for each repository, I have created one service

```
public interface EnityService
{
    Task AddAsync(Entity entity);
}

public interface EntityStatusService
{
   Task AddStatusAsync(EntityStatus entityStatus)
}
```

Those services have been exposed as public interfaces for the handler and not repositories.

Now I really wonder

- Based on DDD and having an entity and its status, should I create two separated repositories or they should be as one repository, as they are one context?
- Do I need to expose the entity and its status through one service?

I wonder if anyone has a suggestion or even a better solution?

Comment: Are your `Entity` and `EntityStatus` closely related? I'm guessing yes but to confirm

Comment: you can think of a report and its status

Answer (score 1):

It appears the EntityStatus should be a property on Entity, but let’s go through the logic to make sure.  Note that these are not hard rules, just my rules of thumb when I’m going through these decisions.  Extenuating circumstances my supersede these.

- Should EntityStatus be an Aggregate Root?  Would it make sense to
  work with an EntityStatus by itself with no relationship to anything
  else, or with only references to child objects?  If not, then it is
  not an Aggregate Root.  That means it’s either a supporting entity or
  a property.
- If the parent entity always has exactly one current value of
  EntityStatus, and no logic needs to be embedded inside the status,
  then it is best to leave it as a property on the Entity.
- If the EntityStatus needs logic built into it then it should probably
  be a value object.  For example, if status can only change from X to
  Y in some circumstances but not others, or if some external process
  must be launched when a status changes, it should be a value object
  whose value is set by the Entity.  Being a value object doesn't necessarily mean it's a separate entity, though.

Finally, I prefer to tie my repositories to Aggregate Roots even if there are value objects owned by the AR.  An AR update should all be saved or nothing, and extending a DB single transaction across repositories is less than ideal.  If you’re using the Unit of Work pattern, then an AR update should be a single unit.  I’ve tried creating a separate repo per table where the AR repo uses the individual table repos, and it felt too granular with all the plumbing code.  It was also easy to lose the business idea you’re trying to accomplish when dealing with all the pieces floating around.  In the end, though, there’s no rule governing this so do what you think is right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DDD expert - just reading through `Implementing DDD` by `Vernon` but from my experience, you have an issue with `bounded context`. Your models `Entity` and `EntityStatus` are probably closely related. In that case you should create `EntityStatusRepository` only if you have a place where you need `EntityStatuses` by itself. If you need both of them just go with `EntityRepository`

Comment: thanks for the answer! it was a good point because I was wondering if I need that status by itself or not. and that made it difficult because at the moment there is no needs but maybe in the future.

Comment: @ShrnPrmshr if that did help you please close your question and approve answar